# Weird jQuery query string appended

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

Can some explain what the "_" value is all about? This is what fiddler is showing me for my MVC 3 page that has a jQuery ajax call on the client.

GET /Services/GetFoodDescriptionsLookup(100)?_=1291727469299 HTTP/1.1

When the URL is constructed in this fashion I don't get back any data, but if I type

GET /Services/GetFoodDescriptionsLookup(100)

this works..

Thank you,
Stephen

Comment: That looks very much like a timestamp added to prevent caching.

Comment: I should clarify that I am getting data back so as not to confuse anyone more than I already am.. :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's added by jQuery to prevent caching when [`cache:false`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) is set. This is basically a workaround for IE's over-eager caching that will not resubmit an AJAX GET request (unless the caching policy is extremely well-configured).

Comment: +1 - I'll add that IE might also choose to cache the hell out of it even when it's configured perfectly.