# How do I reload an <img/>?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, webbrowser-control

I have a WebBrowser control on an WPF page.  The HTML page loaded into the WebBrowser control displays images for the WPF application.  I have a JavaScript callback from the WPF page into the HTML page telling the page that the images have changed and to reload images.  I can't seem to find any way to tell the browser that the underlying file in the  tag has changed.

How do I reload the img?

I've tried just changing the src attribute and I've also tired things like this:

```
            $("#img1").attr("src", "");
            $("#img2").attr("src", "");

            $("#img1").attr("src", image1);
            $("#img2").attr("src", image2);
```

The first time the function is called the images are displayed.  When the image is changed and the function is called again, the original image remains.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Set the source new with a random query part. E.g. img.png?0001 and so on

With this trick every call has a new url and the browser control cannot annoy you with caching stuff.

Comment: I prefer to use the current timestamp - more reliable than random.

Answer (score 3):

Passing a unique querystring parameter will force the image to reload. Many sites  and libraries ([example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4377000/weird-jquery-query-string-appended)) use this technique to ensure a fresh copy of a resource is displayed:

```
$("#img1").attr("src", image1 + '?_=' + new Date().getTime());
$("#img2").attr("src", image2 + '?_=' + new Date().getTime());
```

You'll need to add additional logic if your `image1` or `image2` links already have querystrings.

Comment: `image1 = image1.substring(0,image1.indexOf('?'))` should do the trick.

Comment: @Blazemonger i personally prefer to use tertiary statements with `indexOf('?')` as the condition, but they both accomplish the same thing.